# JPA Query equivalent to finding the top 10 most occurrences of keywords SQL query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a query that outputs (limits) the top 10 records with the most keyword hits. My SQL Query is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wine 
WHERE
    description LIKE '%dry%'
    OR description LIKE '%depth%'
    OR description LIKE '%strong%'
    OR description LIKE '%spicy%'
ORDER BY
    IF(description LIKE '%dry%',1,0)+
    IF(description LIKE '%depth%',1,0)+
    IF(description LIKE '%strong%',1,0)+ 
    IF(description LIKE '%spicy%',1,0)
DESC LIMIT 10;
```

This query works by finding the top 10 records where the descriptions match the keywords (dry, depth, strong, spicy) and then orders them by the number of occurrences of those words.

I am trying to write a JPA query equivalent but am relatively new to it. Would using the `@Query` param in the `WineRepository` be the best option here or should this logic be hardcoded with Java in my `WineService` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pageable` is what you are looking for. If you want to combine a `@Query` annotation with setting maximum results:

```
public interface WineRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Wine,Long> {
  @Query("select * from wine where ...")
  List<Wine> findAllWinesWhereKeywordLikes(Pageable pageable);

  default List<Wine> findTop10WinesWhereKeywordLikes() {
    return findAllWinesWhereKeywordLikes(new PageRequest(0,10));
  }

}
```

> Would using the @Query param in the WineRepository be the best option
>   here or should this logic be hardcoded with Java in my WineService
>   file?

As a manner of fact it is better that you create a method in service that get a list of keywords then search with those keywords across the repository. Because maybe later you need to search with more keywords except (dry, depth, strong, spicy) and you can reuse your service method everywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help and advice. I did end up using Pageable to set the limit.